# Regex not matching tab chars before end of string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, match

I need to filter some lines containing several tabs at the end of the string using a regex.
To do so, I wrote the following code:

```
import re

s = 'text:\t\t\t\t\t'
preg = re.compile(r':\s*$')
print(preg.match(s))
```

Which prints `None` indicating that no match was found. For further investigation I jumped over to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gBhPcT/1/) in order to test the regex more comfortably, which in contrast to Python returns a match as desired.

Where's the problem here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As usual, [use `re.search`](https://ideone.com/8NAVKz). Or, if you use regex101, why not go to the [code generator page?](https://regex101.com/r/gBhPcT/1/codegen?language=python)

Comment: what you want tabs or string only